# Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown line 0

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo

I'm using nginx with php5-fpm and for some reason my php5-fpm has been saying "Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown line 0" and honestly I have no idea why. The extension isn't loaded inside of php.ini but it's loaded from  "--with-config-file-scan-dir" which loads pdo.ini and of course that loads pdo.so

my php config is as follows

`'./configure' '--prefix=/opt/php5' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/php5' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/conf.d' '--with-curl' '--with-pear' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir' '--with-zlib' '--with-xpm-dir' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-t1lib' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-openssl' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--with-bz2' '--with-gettext' '--with-readline' '--with-fpm-user=www-data' '--with-fpm-group=www-data' '--disable-debug' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-cli' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-exif' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-dba' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg'`

I can't seem to find a solution that works for me.

I checked my `phpinfo()` to see if the PDO extension was loaded and it seems to be loaded (even when I remove loading the pdo.so from pdo.ini) yet when I try to use PDO I get

> Fatal Error: Class 'PDO' not found

I'll also point out that I'm also loading `suhosin.so`, `apc.so`, and `imagick.so` with no problems.

List of installed packages (php and mysql) hopefully this can provide some more information to help me out with this. It is also worth noting that my configuration has been working for the past 6 months without a hitch. I installed it using the VladGH install script (https://github.com/vladgh/VladGh.com-LEMP) since it is just my dev environment. If need be I am more than willing to do a complete re-install of my server but I would rather just figure this out.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php
  libapache2-mod-php5                             install
  php5-cgi                                        install
  php5-cli                                        install
  php5-common                                     install
  php5-mysql                                      install
  php5-suhosin                                    install

dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
  courier-authlib-mysql                           install
  libdbd-mysql-perl                               install
  libmysql++3                                     deinstall
  libmysqlclient16                                install
  mysql-client-5.1                                install
  mysql-client-core-5.1                           install
  mysql-common                                    install
  mysql-server                                    install
  mysql-server-5.1                                install
  mysql-server-core-5.1                           install
  php5-mysql                                      install
  postfix-mysql                                   install
```

After trying numerous solutions on how to fix this problem I have just decided to do a complete re-install on my machine.

Comment: Are you using system-provided packages?  If so, which ones are installed?  Ubuntu keeps their PHP version pretty fresh and even builds many PECL extensions, so there's usually no reason to custom-compile...

Comment: Originally I built PHP. Since then I have installed the following through apt-get: php5-dev (which I then removed and purged), php-pear (removed and purged), libmysqlclient-dev & mysql-client (updates), libmysql++-dev, phpize, mongodb. Any ideas, should I recompile PHP through packages?

Comment: Using distro-provided binary packages is *almost always* your best bet instead of compiling yourself.  Each of the `php5-mysql`, `php5-pgsql` and `php5-sqlite` packages provide PDO and drivers.

Comment: re-installed using php5-mysql and I'm still getting the "Already loaded error" except this time it's for mysql, mysqli, pdo, and pdo_mysql. I'm not quite understanding why the heck this thing just won't work. :(

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles! I just ended up re-installing my server after not being able to find any solutions.

Answer (score 5):

[From PHP 5.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration51.databases.php), PDO is part of PHP Core distrib, so `pdo.so` loaded as extension becomes redundant.

Comment: That's what I thought too, however when I remove loading the pdo.so I get the "Fatal Error: Class 'PDO' not found". :\

Comment: You should however load PDO drivers extensions. only base PDO class is bundled with PHP

Comment: How would I go about loading the PDO driver extensions..I thought that would require me doing extension=pdo.so which then throws the error "Module 'PDO' already loaded"? Sorry about all the questions lol, just not quite getting what your saying.

Comment: pdo_mysql or pdo_pgsql are pdo drivers that need to be loaded for PDO to work. these are 'implementations' of PDO. Of course you need to load the one that fits your need, there are a bunch that target many DBs

Comment: I don't have pdo_mysql tried installing with PECL which failed. I should also note that the server has been running fine without this error for about 6 months. Any other suggestions? I'm starting to think if maybe I should just do a full server re-installation :\

Comment: PECL install of pdo_mysql is not the most easy thing since it will try to recompile which supposes having some bunch of dev packages for both php & mysql. could you get one from a binary distribution package (rpm or deb) depending of your linux distro ?

Comment: I actually just got pdo_mysql to compile. Then linked up the .so file included the .so via php extensions and now it's saying "PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0" I'm about to give up on this thing :(

Comment: i suppose the PECL install did put somewhere the inclusion of pdo_mysql as extension.just double check your php.ini and automatically included ini files to see if two of them are trying to load pdo_mysql.

Comment: Just checked and pdo_mysql.so isn't loaded anywhere else. Anymore ideas? :\ Wish there was an easier way to check what else is loading the extension...

Comment: Thanks for the help Dweeves, I really appreciate it! I ended up just re-installing my server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it helped: **apt-get install --reinstall php5-mysql**