# Symfony 3 Doctrine 2 - schema update causes UndefinedFunctionException simplexml_load_file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, xampp

I'm currently working on an Api-platform (Symfony 3.1, Doctrine 2.5) project using Git and XAMPP for Linux (xampp-linux-x64-7.0.9-1). We're encouraged to update our database every time someone changes an Entity. However, when I try to do so, I get this message

```
$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]                                  
  Attempted to call function "simplexml_load_file" from namespace "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver".
```

The stack trace is

```
 () at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php:814
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver->loadMappingFile() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/FileDriver.php:115
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\FileDriver->getElement() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php:58
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver->loadMetadataForClass() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:102
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:151
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:115
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:59
 Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php:50
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand->execute() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:261
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:839
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:116
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/bin/console:29
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174592/call-to-undefined-function-doctrine-orm-mapping-driver-simplexml-load-file) question, which suggests that maybe simplexml is not installed. However, when I run phpinfo shows that it is

```
$ php -i | grep -i simplexml
SimpleXML
Simplexml support => enabled
```

As the problem seemed to be in the Doctrine dependency, I deleted the vendor/ folder and installed all of them again using composer. Sadly, nothing changed. As a last try, I ran the update with the `--dump-sql` option, which gave me the same results.

Has anyone ever had this problem? My guess it's something Linux related, given that the rest of the team work with Windows and never had this issue.

Edit: as suggested in comments, I checked php.ini for a duplicate of the "extension=pdo.so" line, and it only appears once. That part of the file is

```
[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict
;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name
extension=pdo.so
```

If I comment the last line, the warning disappears but the problem continues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 in laravel installation on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292272/module-pdo-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0-in-laravel-installation-on-ubun)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326185/module-pdo-already-loaded-in-unknown-line-0

Comment: https://www.unixmen.com/solved-php-warning-module-pdo-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0/

Comment: php.ini has no duplicate of the pdo extension. I've updated the question